# Laplace transform of integral constant

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, functions, laplace-transform

From the book First course on DE, there's the problem $2y''+ty'-2y=10, y(0)=0, y'(0)=0$. Implying laplace transform to both sides give a linear homogenuous DE $Y'(s)-(2s-\frac{3}{s})Y(s)=-\frac{10}{s^2}$ and it gives $Y=\frac{5}{s^3}+C\frac{e^{s^2}}{s^3}$, but I'm stuck here. The answer is $\frac{5}{2}t^2$, which means that $c=0$. Now I can't find the reason why $c=0$. Can anyone help???

Comment: Can you apply the initial conditions?

Comment: How? Y(s) is not very related to the conditions of y.

Comment: did you tried to back apply the inverse laplace transform and prug the initial conditions, you might end finding the value of C this way

Comment: That was the first approach I tried, but had no idea of the inverse laplace transform of $\frac{e^{s^2}}{s^3}$. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

However I reached the answer using that this is the IVP!
Note that the lVP uniqueness condition satifies to this problem. Now if we plug in the initial condition, then whatever $L^{-1} (\frac{e^{s^2}}{s^3})$ is, if it exists then $C=0$ since $\frac{5}{2}t^2$ is a solution for every single t. I think the approach of calculating $L^{-1} (\frac{e^{s^2}}{s^3})$ is harder.

Comment: Why does the initial condition imply that $C=0$ for all values of $t$? The other answers assume that the function is of exponential order (which then directly implies that $C=0$). I don't see why the two initial conditions imply that $C=0$ for every value of $t$.

Comment: @Axion004 IVP's solution should be unique and $\frac{5}{2}t^2$ is already a solution for the given IVP for all t. Now we can check that $C=0$ or $L^{-1} (\frac{e^{s^2}}{s^3})=0$ but the second one is absurd.

Answer (score 3):

Apply the exponential order property of fuctions.

Definition: A function $f$ is said to be of exponential order $c$ if there exist constants $c,M>0,T>0$ such that $|f(t)|≤Me^{ct}$ for all $t>T$.

In order for $f(t)$ to have a Laplace Transform then in a race between $|f(t)|$ and $e^{ct}$ as $t\to\infty$ then $e^{ct}$ must approach its limit first, i.e. $\lim_{t\to\infty}\frac{f(t)}{e^{ct}}=0.$

Theorem: If $f$ is piecewise continuous on $[0,\infty)$ and of exponential order $c$, then $F(s)=L[f(t)]$ exists for $s>c$ and $\lim_{s\to\infty}F(s)=0.$

Therefore

$$\lim_{s\to\infty}Y(s)=0$$

implies

$$\lim_{s\to\infty}\frac{5}{s^3}+C\frac{e^{s^2}}{s^3}=0$$

which is true if and only if $C=0$. Thus

$$Y(s)=\frac{5}{s^3}$$

Comment: Forgot about that Thx

Comment: Wait isn't that a if(necessary) statement? It doesn't have to be exponential order to have a laplace transform. The converse holds but does the original statement hold? I've heard about such functions.

Comment: For an exponential order function, we have existence and uniqueness of the Laplace transform. As you point out, the theorem is a sufficient condition for the existence of the Laplace transform. There are [functions that have a Laplace transform](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1270635/are-there-functions-that-are-not-of-exponential-order-for-which-you-can-define-a) which are not of exponential order.

Comment: We have that any polynomial is of exponential order since

$$e^{at}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{t^na^n}{n!}\ge \frac{t^na^n}{n!} \implies t^n\le \frac{n!}{a^n}e^{at}$$

while $f(t)=e^{t^2}$ isn't of exponential order since given $c>0$

$$\lim_{t\to\infty}\frac{e^{t^2}}{e^{ct}}=\lim_{t\to\infty}e^{t(t-c)}=\infty$$

and for $c \le 0$ we have

$$\lim_{t\to\infty}{e^{t^2+ct}}=\infty$$

Comment: I think the IVP condition solves it. Can you take a look?

Answer (score 0):

We have

$~\mathcal L\{y(t)\}=\bar y(p)~$

$\mathcal L\{y'(t)\}=p~\bar y(p)-y(0)=p~\bar y(p)~~~~$ (as it is given that $~y(0)=0~$)

$\mathcal L\{y''(t)\}=p^2~\bar y(p)-p~y(0)-y'(0)=p^2~\bar y(p)~~~~$(as it is given that $~y(0)=0,~y'(0)=0$)

$\mathcal L\{ty'(t)\}=-\dfrac{d}{dp}\{p~\bar y(p)\}=-\bar y(p)-p~\dfrac{d\bar y}{dp}~$

Now given equation is 
$$2y''+ty'-2y=10$$
Taking Laplace transform both side we have 
$$2~\mathcal L\{y''\}+\mathcal L\{ty'\}-2\mathcal L\{y\}=\mathcal L\{10\}$$
$$\implies 2p^2\bar y(p)-\bar y(p)-p~\dfrac{d\bar y}{dp}-2\bar y(p)=\dfrac{10}{p}$$
$$\implies \dfrac{d\bar y}{dp}+\left(\dfrac{3}{p}-2p\right)\bar y(p)=-\dfrac{10}{p^2}\tag1$$

Which is a first order linear differential equation.

Integrating factor (I.F.) $$~=e^{\int\left(\frac{3}{p}-2p\right)dp}=e^{3\ln p-p^2}=p^3e^{-p^2}~$$

Multiplying both side of $(1)$ by the I.F. we have
$$p^3e^{-p^2}\dfrac{d\bar y}{dp}+e^{-p^2}(3p^2-2p^4)\bar y(p)=-10pe^{-p^2}$$
$$\implies \dfrac{d}{dp}\left\{p^3e^{-p^2}\bar y\right\}=-10pe^{-p^2}$$
Integrating we have,
$$p^3e^{-p^2}\bar y=-10\int pe^{-p^2}$$
$$\implies p^3e^{-p^2}\bar y=5e^{-p^2}+c$$
$$\implies \bar y=\dfrac{1}{p^3}\left(c~e^{p^2}+5\right)\tag2$$where $~c~$ is integrating constant.

Now by the definition $~\bar y(p)=\int^{\infty}_0 y(t)e^{-pt}dt~,~$which$~~\to 0~$ if $~p\to\infty~$. So from $(2)$, $~c=0~$.

Therefore  $$ \bar y=\dfrac{5}{p^3}$$

So

$~y(t)=\mathcal L^{-1}\{\bar y(p)\}~$

$~~~~~~=5~\mathcal L^{-1}\left\{\dfrac{1}{p^3}\right\}$

$~~~~~~=5\dfrac{t^2}{2}$

Comment: Again why should $\bar y \to 0 $when $p\to\infty$?

Comment: If $p\to \infty$ then $e^{-pt}\to 0$, and therefore the integral and finally $\bar y(p)$

Comment: but $y(t)$ can be non exponential order.

Comment: I think this link may help you "https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/859407/laplace-transform-non-exponential-order"

Comment: Umm I still don't get it. So I know that there exists non-exponential order functions which have a laplace transform. Why can't $y(t)$ be one of those??

Comment: Look there is no $~f(t)~$ for which $~\mathcal L\{f(t)\}=F(p)=\dfrac{e^{p^2}}{p^3}~$.